# I re-installed ubuntu 14.04 and it won't boot

Tags: boot, grub2

I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04, and I can't get it to boot or do anything. I'm not even getting an error message, just the black screen with the flashing underscore. I don't have a Windows dual-boot set up.

The motherboard is a Asrock Z77 Extreme.

It has worked before, but now no matter how often I reinstall and in whichever way possible, it will not boot. I did format before installing, my vid card is a 280x. Install was done from normal bios and not uefi.

Solution: holding shift and entering nomodeset made it boot.

Comment: Did you format the partition on which you've installed Ubuntu ?

Comment: What video card? Often if AMD or nVidia you need nomodeset. And with Asrock you must not have any drive in the Asmedia ports. Did you install in BIOS or UEFI boot mode? At grub menu you can use e for edit, scroll to linux line and replace quiet splash with nomodeset. If only Ubuntu then you may not get grub menu unless you hold shift key from BIOS or with UEFI hit escape key.

Comment: I don't even know what asmedia ports are. I'll try booting while holding shift and then inserting the nomodeset. I'll report back here tonight.

Comment: at the moment it's working but I have to add nomodeset everytime I start up, can't I make this permanent?

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>

Then run the following commands:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo service lightdm start
```